# Bootstrap Colorpicker change color simultaneously

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I want to change the background color to some of my li's simultaneously:

.set-color is the class for each a in li.

jQuery:

```
$('.set-color').each(function(index, el) {
    var currentColor = $(this).data('color');
    $(this).ColorPickerSliders({
    size: 'sm',
    placement: 'left',
    swatches: false,
    sliders: false,
    hsvpanel: true,
    onchange: function(container, color) {
        var colorRGB = 'rgba('+ color.rgba.r +','+ color.rgba.g +','+ color.rgba.b +',1)';
        var rgbToHex = rgb2hex( colorRGB );
        $.each(stuff, function(index, val) {
            // stuff is an array and in each item I want to change the color
            if (stuff.color == currentColor) {
                stuff.color == rgbToHex;
            };
        });
    }
  });
});
```

HTML li structure:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" class="set-color" data-color="#da8ba3">
        <span>ORDER</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I don't know if I changed the code correctly because it is a lot of other stuff in my code. I tried to simplify it as much as I could.

The color picker changes the color of stuff but only once. If I want to change the color I have to click again on my .set-color.

My problem is that I don't know how to update `currentColor` on `ColorPickerSliders` `onchange`. So when the `ColorPickerSliders` changes I have to update the `currentColor` and after that to make the `$.each(stuff, ...` and the `if` condition.

EDIT: stuff is:

If I console.log(stuff) before $.each( stuff, etc ... I have this:

[image: STUFF image]

Comment: Please, what is `stuff` and where does it come from?

Comment: stuff it is an array with all paths of the current activeObject. I will update the question with how the array looks.

Comment: I updated the question with a picture of how the stuff looks.

Comment: What are you trying to update in the each? `stuff.color` does not exist in your array. `val.color` would make more sense but even then in your array color doesnt exist as a key

Comment: It that array (the posted picture) I have 0 with fill: #da8ba3, 1 with fill #cccccc, 2 with fill: #eaeaea, 3 with fill same as 0, and so on (different colors or not ). For example. I have 0, 3, 10, 11 and 15 with the same fill. I want when the colorpicker changes to update the fill value of those 0, 3, 10, 11 and 15.